# partially commutative like monoids

Tags: gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $G$ be a simple graph with vertex $I$ and edge set $E$. I am defining $M(G)$ to be the quotient of the free monoid $I^*$ on $I$ by the relations $ab=ba$ and $c^2 = 1$ (empty word) whenever $\{a,b\} \notin E(G)$ and $c \in I$ is arbitrary.

I have the following questions about the monoid $M(G)$.

1. Is this monoid $M(G)$ well studied in the literature?
2. What are some algebraic combinatorics or general combinatorial significance of this monoid?

Thanks for your time and have a good day.

Comment: It is called Right Angled Coxeter Group (RACG). Google it.

Comment: I agree with YCor,  you should have edited your old question.

Comment: Perhaps the Right-Angled Coxeter Monoid (for the complement of $G$)?

Comment: @AlexSuciu as Mark has mentioned, it's a monoid presentation obviously defining a group (as does any Coxeter presentation).